# How to use multiple Hard drives in Ubuntu linux?

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, ssd

I have a desktop computer and in it there are two hard drives, one SSD and one HDD. I use the SSD for boot that works fine but I want to use the HDD for my files how can I do that.
Thanks

Comment: What files. Generally you want / (root) and probably /home's hidden user settings in SSD as they are accessed the most. And most data is not accessed often, so being on a slower hard drive is fine. You can put some data on SSD, but then have to manage how much so not to fill SSD unless you have a very large SSD.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to make a partition auto mounted in Ubuntu.

Run:
`sudo blkid`

You will see UUIDs of your partitions, the next is just an example:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="B23613F43613B875" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Windows" UUID="38CE9483CE943AD8" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Data" UUID="519CB82E5888AD0F" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="00d7d951-2a35-40fd-8e5d-411bb824ff3b" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda6: LABEL="Ubuntu" UUID="6044b1d0-208e-4ab3-850d-03a92e1516fc" TYPE="ext4"
```

You shall take a UUID from your output which is corresponding to the partition you are going to automount:

`sudo gedit /etc/fstab`

For a general-purpose read-write mount, add this line to the end of /etc/fstab:

for *ext4*

```
UUID=6044b1d0-208e-4ab3-850d-03a92e1516fc /disk-sda5-kubuntu     ext4    defaults         0     2
```

or for *NTFS*

```
UUID=519CB82E5888AD0F  /media/Data  ntfs-3g  defaults,windows_names,locale=en_US.utf8  0 0
```

**but change UUID to yours.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what problem you have but you can normally access your partitions on both; your SSD and your HDD without doing anything. Just go to "files" and you should find the partitions listed on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the drive to your PC and start Ubuntu.

It will recognize the drive automaticly and you can find it  in the unity dock at the bottom or in the file browser on the left.

You may need to format you drive